# Error while testing Ember Components

Tags: testing, ember.js, components

I want to test my ember component. I am not using ember-cli.I followed what was given in ember guidelines. But this.subject() method is undefined.
Also, I got the following error

```
setUp failed on <test-case-name> : assert.async is not a function
Died on test #2 : this.render is not a function
TearDown Failed on <test-case-name> : assert.async is not a function
```

I haven't used any async functions. In my test-case, I wrote a single line this.render() alone.

Thanks in Advance,
KuKa

Comment: The 2.0 guides use ember-cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in Ember 2.0, you are writing an integration test, not a unit test. And for some reason, you are not permitted access to the component object in an integration test.

To make your test a unit test, add `unit: true` to the test module definition:

```
moduleForComponent('pretty-color', {
  unit: true,
  // specify the other units that are required for this test
  // needs: ['component:foo', 'helper:bar']
});
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is currently out of date and does not discuss component integration tests. To learn more about integration tests, see http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-component-integration-tests/

Comment: Thank you so much Gaurav